# Is there anyway to expand image on hover like bing image search?

Tags: php, css, image

I have a search result which includes images. When the user hover over the image, the image should expand like we see in bing http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=world&go=&form=QBIR&qs=n . Please help.

Comment: Can you use a javascript library like jQuery?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075320/how-does-bing-com-create-enlarged-thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

It's all javascript and CSS. There has to be a jQuery or some other JS Library plugin for it but I don't know one off hand.  [Here](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/) is a tutorial on how to get a similar effect using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look into javascript frameworks

- [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org)/[scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/)
- [Ext core](http://www.extjs.com/products/extcore/)
- [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

All of those would be able to implement such effects, if you want the exact same effect let me  know which framework you want to use I would provide a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery then you can write

[animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate)

function on

[hover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover)

event.

In the animate function change the width and height to your desired one.

Comment: if i change the height and width it only crops and not the whole image is enlarged. Please help